# Discrete mathematics problem - Probability theory and counting

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm taking a discrete mathematics course, and I encountered a question and I need your help. I don't know if this is the right place for that though :)

It says:

Each user on a computer system has a password, which is six to eight characters long, where each character is an uppercase letter or a digit. Each password must contain at least one digit. How many possible passwords are there?

The book solves this by adding the probabilities of having six,seven and eight characters long password. However, when he solves for probability of six characters he does this

```
P6 = 366 - 266
```

and does

```
P7 = 367 - 267
```

and

```
P8 = 368 - 268
```

and then add them all.

I understand the solution, but my question is why doesn't calculating, P6 = 10*36<sup>5</sup> and the same for P7 and P8, work?
10 for the digit and 36 for the alphanumeric?

Also, if anyone could give me another solution, other than the one in the book.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: According to the question, `123456` it qualifies as containing a minimum of one digit with the rest of the characters being alphanumeric, so it is indeed valid.  However, so are `A1B2CD` and `EFG9H0`, so while such an optimization would be easy in programming, it makes the resulting expression more complex, assuming you were intending to optimize the calculation of the result.

Comment: So what's the optimized solution that you have Dustin?

And not really, I don't need the optimization, if you wer talking to me initially

Comment: I think there's an inclination of understanding that an element can only be used once. That's not the case as can be seen from the book's solution. @Mohammed - what's with the "10*36^5"?

Comment: @Longpoke:  Mathoverflow.net is intended for professional mathematicians and advanced students.  This question is way too elementary for that forum.

Answer (score 3):

You're forgetting that the number can be in any position.

Comment: So multiplying by six would do the job?

I tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the solution, but my
>   question is why doesn't calculating,
>   P6 = 10*36^5 and the same for P7 and
>   P8, work? 10 for the digit and 36 for
>   the alphanumeric?

you're guaranteeing that there is a digit by using the 10,
but, there's nothing to stop there from being a digit in the other positions (36 choices)
that's why you have to get all the combs in which there are digits and subtract all the ones where there aren't
which leads to P6 = 36^6 - 26^6

If I think if an alternate solution I'll revisit this post, but for now I don't see why you wouldn't be satisfied with the provided one, knowing why yours doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you do it like `36^5 * 10`, that means "take the first five positions and put some random letters/digits there and fill the sixth (and only the sixth) position with a digit" - but your digit can be in each place.

Consider the following: If you set 5 places with letters/digits, then putting a digit in the sixth place yields 10 possibilities (the sixth position can then hold every number from 0 to 9), and if you put the digit in front of the letters, this would yield another 10 possibilities (then, the first place could contain every digit from 0 to 9), so by multipliing by 10 you forget some possibilities.

If you want to calculate it "the raw way", you could do the following (I do it with six places, you can adapt it to 7 or 8). Since a password must contain at least one digit, it can hold 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 digits, resp 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 or 0 letters.

If you have `k` digits in 6 places in total, there are `6 over k` possibilities to choose these `k` places. Each of these `k` places can be filled with a digit, so you have `10^k` possibilities for the digits and `26^(6-k)` possibilities for letters.

So, for `k` digits, you have `10^k * 26^(6-k)` possibilities. Thus, since you can distribute the `k` digits in `6 over k` ways, you have

`sum(k from 1 to 5: (6 over k) * 10^k * 26^(6-k)) = 36^6-26^6`

possibilities in total.